# 9/11 attack: How can a whole building fall even though impact only on the top of building?

Tags: elasticity, structural-beam

The airplane hit the top of the building. After a few time the whole building collapsed. How is this physically possible?

Answer (score 4):

To state the physics of this question: fire raises the temperature of load bearing steel. The latter's mechanical properties radically change - yield strength in particular drops radically - leading to structural failure under normally well bearable loads.

The engineering stuff: Steel is a known, severe fire hazard in this way, but its strength and low weight make it indespensible in building. Therefore, design uses both redundant load bearing members and shielding of steel in concrete shells to make sure that (1) a fire that can be put out will not bring the building down or (2) that there is enough time to get people out if the fire cannot be quenched before the steel structure heats enough to yield.

Believe it or not, the designers of the World Trade Center would have considered the possility of an aircraft strike: several large aircraft have stricken towers in New York in the last 70 years, through mistaken navigation. There was never any possibility that the aircraft would have brought the towers down immediately.

If you read the Wikipedia articles on the [Collapse of the World Trade Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collapse_of_the_World_Trade_Center) it gives you a good summary of the physics, design criteria and engineering factors. One of the main causes of the collapse was found to be the fact that steel members had their *fireproofing blown away by the collisions and explosions straight afterwards*.